# Set Value of 1000 records through Ajax quickly?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, performance

I have 1000 records and I want to set value for each of them through Ajax. It's working very slow, I need to improve the performance. What can I do to improve the performance? Following is my current code:

```
$(".Record").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    GetData($this.attr("id"), $this);
});

function GetData(value,element) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Employees")',
        data: { id: value },
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            element.text(data);
        }
    });
}
```

And here is my Action:

```
public JsonResult GetData(int id)
{
    var Employee = db.Employees.Where(x => x.Id == id).First();
    var Data = Activity.ActivityStatus.StatusEn;
    return Json(Data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: This should be asked on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions), not SO

Comment: You should do only one ajax. Collect data and then send an array of id's to controller.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok. I will ask it there.

Comment: agree to @StephenMuecke. making 1000 requests from client to update 1000 records is not gonna work for real apps - due to network/client threshold/limitations. Being slow is obvious.